# Как на jquery при закрытии вкладки показать сообщение?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть вкладка в которой открыта страничка, как сделать так, чтобы показался alert с текстом, когда человек попытается закрыть вкладку?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если версия `jQuery` выше `1.8`:

```
$(window).bind("beforeunload", function() { 
    return confirm("Do you really want to close?"); 
})
```

Ниже:

```
$(window).unload(function() {
    alert("Bye me!");
})
```

Пробуйте.

***UPDATE:***

```js
jQuery(window).bind('beforeunload', function(e) {
    var message = "Why are you leaving?";
    e.returnValue = message;
    return message;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://www.google.com">Exit</a>
```

***UPDATE #2:***

```js
$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
  return 'Your own message goes here...';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://google.com">Exit!</a>
```

Comment: В firefox не работает почему то

Comment: @Анатолий Какой вариант пробовали? Рекомендую использовать первый вариант.

Comment: ДА я тут на локалке делаю, пробовал оба варианта

Comment: В фоксе когда по ссылка переход то работает, но когда закриваю окно то неработает

Comment: @Анатолий первый вообще не работает, или только в firefox?

Comment: первый  в firefox работает только когда по ссылкам переход делаеш, а в хроме работает как положено

Comment: @Анатолий Сделал пример, все работает, проверил в firefox, внес немного изменений.

Comment: странно, у меня в firefox только при переходам по ссылкам работает, а так потянулся к крестику для закрития вкладки, закрил и все сообщения нет, а вот в хроме все работает, ну ладно буду искать дальше, решение этой задачи.

Comment: Хорошо, а е есть вариант показать сообщение когда человек потянулся к закрытии вкладки, такое часто в лендингах видел.

Comment: @Анатолий вы версию jQuery смотрели, которую подключаете?

Comment: Да, я вашу с примера взял был 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43861/discussion-between-nikita-smith-and-).